# Creating Generic Adapter Pattern and what is "Realization of a deque"?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am really new to datastructures and algorithms and I really feel this stuff is going right over my head so I was wondering if anyone has a simplified version of explaining this...

I am trying to make a generic adapter class using the sequence ADT using an Arraylist.

So, I really have no idea what methods to even begin to make here...

Am I suppose to make methods such as size(), isEmpty(), get(0), get(size -1), add(0,e), add(size,e), remove(0), remove(size-1) ?

Here is what I have thus far:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package adapterexample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author owner
 */
public interface Sequence<E> extends Deque<E>, IndexList<E>, PositionList<E> {

   ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();


  /** Returns the position containing the element at the given index. */
  public Position<E> atIndex(int r) throws BoundaryViolationException;

  /** Returns the index of the element stored at the given position. */
  public int indexOf(Position<E> p) throws InvalidPositionException;

  /** Add element to the array **/
  public E add(int i, E e){

  }

  //continue methods here?

}
```

Also, I came across methods compared with deque methods and realization with Arraylist methods... What does "*realization with ...*" even mean? or "*realization of...*"

Thanks everyone.

Comment: You know, deque is `FIFO`, which means `first in first out`, you need to add methods to match this property based on ArrayList. And, some `interfaces` are the same as that in `ArrayList`, you need not to change them.

Comment: @zybjtu that is all set up already,there are 6+ classes including exception handling. just not sure how to tie it all together with the arraylist.